# Android, CMDTool, stdout redirect, "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)"

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, android-source

### Use-case

Android C++ command-line tool lunching "/system/bin/getprop" and redirecting it's stdout to a socket

### Problem

Lunching 'getprop' fails with "F/libc    (20694): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 20694 (getprop)", code & logcat snippet follow.

Why do I get the SIGSEGV? Why does teh forked process fail ?

### Implementation

```
HRESULT ServiceCore::CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout(IN char* pCmd, IN char** args, OUT SOCKET& stdoutstream) {
    HRESULT hr      = S_OK;
    int     fds[2]  = { 0 };
    pid_t   pid     = 0;
    stdoutstream = 0;
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == socketpair(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds))
        goto ErrExit;
    stdoutstream = fds[1];
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
        goto ErrExit;
    if (pid == 0) {
        // The newly created process
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ServiceCore", "CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '%s' started", pCmd);
        int newfd = dup2(fds[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ServiceCore", "CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '%s' newfd:%d, oldfd:%d", pCmd, newfd, fds[0]);
        _ASSERT(newfd == STDOUT_FILENO);

        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
        execvp(pCmd, args);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ServiceCore", "CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '%s' FAILED", pCmd);
        exit(1);
    }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ServiceCore", "CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '%s(%d)' Created", pCmd, pid);
    return S_OK;
ErrExit:
    if (0 != pid)
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
    stdoutstream = 0;
    return hr;
}

...
        char* args[] = { 0 };
        SOCKET soc;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout("/system/bin/getprop", args, soc))) {
            errno = 0;
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ServiceCore", "SendConfig>> Reading props");
            char pTmp[256000];
            int iRet = read(soc, pTmp, sizeof(pTmp));// Read the first few lines
        }

...
```

### logcat

```
I/ServiceCore(20689): CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '/system/bin/getprop(20694)' Created

I/ServiceCore(20689): SendConfig>> Reading props

I/ServiceCore(20694): CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '/system/bin/getprop' started

I/ServiceCore(20694): CreateProcessAndRedirectStdout>> '/system/bin/getprop' newfd:1, oldfd:10

F/libc    (20694): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 20694 (getprop)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question in this?

Comment: Sounds like something is dereferencing a null pointer. You'll need to look at the stack trace in the logcat output to figure out where, which should lead you to the what/why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing execvp() in a way which `getprop` is not written to handle.  To quote from an OSX/BSD (but effectively generic) manual page for execvp()

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvP() functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available
>        to the new program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to
>        the file name associated with the file being executed.  The array of
>        pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

You are breaking this convention, by passing an array of one NULL element, when **you should be passing the name of the program as the first element, followed by a terminating NULL element.**

This sets `getprop` up to fail as it considers the possibility of having only one argument (itself) in which case it will show everything.

```
    if (argc == 1) {
        list_properties();
```

But if it does not have 1 argument, it *assumes* it must have two or more, and attempts to de-reference the second one, which *should* be the name of the property you want to get.

```
    property_get(argv[1], value, default_value);
```

Passing an invalid and likely null pointer in place of a property name to property_get() ultimately fails deep inside bionic libc, likely where the implementation of __system_property_find() calls strlen().

If you had examined the stack trace as fadden suggested, you would probably see an address in libc, likely strlen().